# Good practice for interacting with a database using flask

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, contextmanager

I'm writing some functions to interact with an sqlite3 database using Flask. I was hoping to get some feedback on whether or not this solution was good practice.

Essentially, both the connection and cursor are given within a context manager which is entered before every request and exited using teardown_appcontext.

Is setting up a cursor before every request good practice or is it better to only create it if needed?
Also, is using context managers for this good practice?

One small issue i seem to be having with this approach is that if there is an exception, it can be hard to trace as the context managers and teardown_appcontext continue to operate after the exception is raised.

```
    import sqlite3
    import contextlib
    from typing import Optional
    from flask import current_app, g


    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def get_connection():
        db_connection = sqlite3.connect(current_app.config['DATABASE'])
        db_connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        try:
            print("Getting connection")
            yield db_connection
        except Exception:
            db_connection.rollback()
            print("Database exception")
            raise
        else:
            db_connection.commit()
        finally:
            print("Connection closed")
            db_connection.close()


    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def get_cursor():
        with get_connection() as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            try:
                print("Getting cursor")
                yield cursor
            finally:
                print("Cursor closed")
                cursor.close()


    @current_app.before_request
    def setup_cursor():
        if "db" not in g:
            g.db_session = get_cursor()
        # Enter the get cursor context which in turn enters the connection context
        g.cursor = g.db_session.__enter__()


    @current_app.teardown_appcontext
    def close_cursor(e: Optional[BaseException] = None) -> None:
        db_session = g.pop('db_session', None)

        if db_session is not None:
            # Exit the cursor context which in turn exits the connection context
            db_session.__exit__(e, None, None)
```

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM like SQLAlchemy? Could help in many ways.